# Output only when asynchronous calls complete inside loop

Tags: javascript

I'm using Google places API and trying to get the value of placeTable.  When I try to update at the end the variable is empty.

```
var placeTable;

function callback(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            var request = { placeId: results[i].place_id };

            service.getDetails(request, callbacks);

            placeTable = "<table>";

            function callbacks(place, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                  placeTable += "<tr><td>" + place.name + "</td><td>" + place.vicinity + "</td></tr>";
              }
            }
            container.innerHTML += placeTable + "</table>";
        }

    }
}
```

**Update:**
With all the input I was able to adjust my code and count the responses.

```
function callback(results, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

      var j = 0;
      var placeTable = "<table>";

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

            var request = { placeId: results[i].place_id };

            service.getDetails(request, callbacks);

            function callbacks(place, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

                  j++;

                  placeTable += "<tr><td>" + place.name + "</td><td>" + place.vicinity + "</td></tr>";

                  if(results.length === j){

                  container.innerHTML += placeTable + "</table>";

                  }
              }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Place all of your `placeTable` code inside of the callback. If you need multiple ones then save all the placeTable calls in your callback and once you've hit the amount of requests sent (and gotten the same amount of responses back) you can write everything. You can't expect async calls to work with non-async code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`callbacks` may be called sometime in future. So your line:

```
container.innerHTML += placeTable + "</table>";
```

Is being executed before `callbacks` function is called.

**UPDATE:** refactored code:

```
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        return;
    }

    var placeTable = "<table>";
    var detailsDone = 0;

    function callbacks(place, status) {
        detailsDone += 1;

        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            placeTable += "<tr><td>" + place.name + "</td><td>" + place.vicinity + "</td></tr>";
        }

        if (detailsDone >= results.length) {
            container.innerHTML += placeTable + "</table>";
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        service.getDetails({
            placeId: results[i].place_id
        }, callbacks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not called here? service.getDetails(request, callbacks);

Comment: No, `service.getDetails(request, callbacks);` only registers your `callbacks` function for the API to call after it gathers and prepares data. That will happen sometime later. Just like you would use `setTimeout` instead, e.g., `setTimeout(callbacks, 0)`.

Comment: Ok, I understand that it is asynchronous now, how do I detect if all the calls are completed?

Comment: You already know how many places you want details about. Keep some variable that you can update whenever `callbacks` is called. When that variable's value becomes equal to number of places, you will know it was called for all of them.

Comment: I updated my answer with refactored version of your code. I did not test it, so it may contain bugs, but it's just to show you which way you can try to go with the code. I would probably change it more, to accept callback and call it with generated chunk of HTML (or even just a array with data, and let the caller generate HTML from that) instead of changing DOM directly from this function.

Comment: Ok great, I just made the change on my code when you posted. All works now.